# Automatically translated resources in Android

Tags: android, string

Does anyone know if there are string resources that are automatically translated to the user's language?

I observed the Google "Sign in" button text has this characteristic of adapting to the user's language

[image: Google sign in button]

xml: com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton/>

Any other resources with this behaviour there?

I would need for my app some common words like: Email, Message, Logout, Call, Loading, Select all, Settings, Delete.

I know about the hard-way method  (values-fr > strings...) but I hope that Google translated the common words for us somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can create localizable strings. In `res` folder, create a `values-<locale>`. And inside, create a `strings.xml` file containing the translated strings.

Example folder

```
values-ja
```

Example strings

```
<string name="app_name">私のアプリケーション</string>
```

When you change your phone language, your app will change to your desired localization if it is available.

For more info, check [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Comment: I know about this method but I hope that Google translated the common words for us somewhere